# How to use app.all to send req.path to a different domain?

Tags: express

In my current environment, this works:

```
router.get("/test", function(req,res,next){
    request({
        uri: 'http://my_virtual_machine:8080/rest/stuff/test',
    }).pipe(res)
})
```

This works in that, when I send a request to `http://localhost:3000/test` I get the expected response from `http://my_virtual_machine:8080/rest/stuff/test/`. But, I'd rather not rewrite every single api.

**Is there a way to simply pass `req.path` along to the VM?**

I tried this:

```
router.all("*", function(req,res,next){
    request({
        uri: 'http://my_virtual_machine:8080/' + req.path,
    }).pipe(res)
})
```

But when I request `http://localhost:3000/test` I get this error -

> `GET http://localhost:3000/test 404 (Not Found)`

Also, I have to send all the HTTP commands (GET, POST, PUT, etc), that's why I'm using `all`, as it was my understanding that `all` "matches all HTTP verbs" [[doc](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.all)].

Comment: router.use('/:path', etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `router.all` to `router.use`, and removed the path parameter. This worked is what worked:

```
router.use(function(req,res,next){
    request({
        uri: 'http://my_virtual_machine:8080' + req.path,
    }).pipe(res)
})
```

Thanks to @yBrodosky for his comment which led me in the right direction. After reading the [docs for `router.use`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.use) I saw that when it has no path parameter, it applies to all urls. And since I am using this as strictly a conduit for VM access (in order to apply an access-control header), that is what I had to do.